# Code Splitting with Webpack for Intl polyfill

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-intl

I'm trying to create a bundle for the `intl` polyfill to load it only for browser which requires it.

Using the following code, it creates the bundle in my output folder

```
if (!window.Intl) {
  require.ensure(['intl/dist/Intl'], (require) => {
    window.Intl = require('intl/dist/Intl');
  }, 'intl-bundle');
}
```

The first thing I noticed is the size of the file is huge, it contains all the languages, is there a way to define the languages I want?

The other issue is that when the browser tries to download the file, it tries from the root folder of my app. So instead of downloading `http://mydomain/js/1.intl-bundle.js`, it tries to get `http://mydomain/1.intl-bundle.js`

Is there a way to set from where the file should be downloaded?

My `webpack.config.js` output looks like this:

```
output: {
  path: './js/',
  filename: '[name].js'
},
```

And the last question, can I remove the `1.` at the beginning of the name of the file, just to have `intl-bundle.js`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually going to answer a few of my own question as I just found some of the solution after a few hours of research.

For the second question, I wasn't defining the `publicPath` in my build, which was the reason why the browser was downloading the file from the root of my domain. More info: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath

```
output: {
  path: './js/',
  publicPath: './js/'
}
```

For the last question, you can name your chunks with the following:

```
output: {
  chunkFilename: '[id]-[name]-[chunkhash].js'
}
```

This allows you to decide the name of your chunks.

I still don't have any answer to reduce the size of the intl file.